# Upgrade scenario: Oracle 8.0.5.0.0 to Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, upgrade, oracle-12c

we have a very old Oracle 8.0.5.0.0 database here that - unfortunately - is still used heavily as every day production system.

I want to start making plans on how to get this DB upgrade to a recent Oracle 12c.

Unfortunately, both DB versions don't seem to be able to talk to each other anymore (*). So to my current knowledge, the only solution is to import daily backups from 8.0.5.0.0 into 12c, which - from the technical point of view - works, but is not feasible because the 8.0.5.0.0 is used in daily business. Beside: The data on the 8.0.5.0.0 server is that large that an import of the backup in the 12c server (on a recent Dell server) takes about 6-8 hours.

So, the question is:

**What might be a good approach for a upgrade strategy from 8.0.5.0.0 to 12c?**

Thanks for any input.

(*) Of course old Oracle 8.0.5.0.0 clients can talk to the Oracle 8.0.5.0.0 server and recent 12c clients can talk to the 12c server. But there does not seem to be a client solution that can talk to both 8.0.5.0.0 *and* 12c.

Comment: I think you're going to have to take some downtime here. Are there any bigger tables that have essentially read-only data sets, or are partitionable  so that you can move some data off in advance? If you can upgrade the 8.0.5 to 8.1.7, things get a little easier as you can then do one intermediate upgrade and use transportable tablespaces. Otherwise you're pretty much stuck with exp/imp. What sort of database is it? Reporting/OLTP/hybrid? What data volumes are we talking about here?

Comment: Thanks Phil for you input!

I think, the biggest problem is the "take some downtime" part as 30-40 users are connected every day between 6 a.m. and 6 p.m. and do read and write transactions every minute. I currently have no idea on how to cope with that in a reasonable manner.

There are of course tables that are _mostly_ read from, but most of the huge, essential tables are written to by the users above, so there would not be much gain in moving off the few read-only tables.

Type of database: Hybrid - we do reporting and OLTP in it.

Data volumes: Daily backup is ~ 6 GB and counting.

Comment: So you can have downtime between 6pm and 6am? 6Gb is a fairly small volume these days

Comment: So what would we gain, if we would take down the 8.0.5 DB between office hours? Ok, importing a 8.0.5 backup into 12c. But it would only take few hours until the 12c DB's data would be out-dated because users start working again on the 8.0.5.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get at. You need to work out a cutover strategy so that you don't lose any data. That will have to involve downtime, but if you can do the data migration in stages it'll minimise the amount of downtime between downing the 8.0.5 database and going live with the 12c database

Comment: 6GB import takes 6-8 hours? It sounds like you have some performance issues on the new system there.

Comment: @dwjv: I don't deny that. First of all, I'm glad it actually worked. It seems that I am the first one in the company that actually tried to import a 8.0.5 backup at all - in 30 years.

Comment: Your options are pretty limited coming from 8i.  It may be possible to use something like Golden Gate for a zero downtime upgrade, that would be very expensive and probably not an option if you're a smaller shop.  You probably just need bite the bullet on this one and accept the downtime.

Comment: supporting @Phil here why is a downtime out of office hours not acceptable and since we are talking about a rather tiny database you should be done with exp/imp in less than an hour?

Comment: @BLT: Well like I said above: What would we actually gain? As soon as users start working again on the 8.0.5 the 12c's data would be out-dated again. Having one half of the users work on the 8.0.5 and the other one on the 12c would probably result in a inconsistency nightmare. Some kind of "bidirectional live mirroring" of every transaction between 8.0.5 and 12c was something I had thought of first.

Comment: Guys, you all rock!! Also the ones below. I still have to gain some reputation here to upvote the answers. Thanks for this huge amount of input. Never thought, that I would get this much help!

I'll definitely look into improving the IMP performance, considering virtualization for the upgrade path and Golden Gate.

You gave me many good arguments that I can use to confront our decision makers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem but the driving issues are cost, allowable downtime and complexity.

- [Golden Gate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/ggzerodowntimedatabaseupgrades-174928.pdf) could be purchased with a one year license and will do a zero downtime upgrade from Oracle 8i to 12. You still have to upgrade from 8.05 to 8i.
- Your life could be simplified by using [VmWare P2V](http://www.vmware.com/ca/en/products/converter) to convert the machine to a virtual machine without any downtime.  This method allows you to:

  - get your production database on better hardware which should improve the speed of most operations
  - allows you to make a copy of the machine, put it on a different subnet and start testing various strategies
- I have imported schemas from our Oracle 8i database directly into Oracle 11.2 without issues.  Your mileage may vary depending on character sets, licensed features and any unorthodox strategies your programmers have in the PL/SQL code.

One method that could be easily tested:

- buy a new server with some serious hardware like 32GB RAM, install VMWare Esxi
- convert your old machine to a virtual
- create a development copy of the Oracle 8.05
- install another virtual machine with Oracle 12
- install another virtual machine with Oracle 10XE or 11XE
- take snapshots of all the machines with no changes
- take an export of the 8.05 development, import into Oracle 10XE or 11XE, test and verify
- data pump to the 12 database
- verify the data on 12 and offline the 8.05 and oracle 10XE or 11XE

This method needs downtime. A weekend should be more than adequate and only costs you a new server, Oracle 12 licence and some VMWare software licenses.  Keep in mind that testing and verification can take more time than importing the data.

Answer (score 3):

This is more an extended comment than a full answer.

There are various ways to do the migration:

1. `exp`/`imp` is a good good way if it is possible between versions that differ this much. I think the main reason why export/import is slow is that there is only one job that does the work. You can accelerate the export/import if you group your tables and do the export/import of these groups in parallel. Also, index creation and constraint enabling can be taken away from the import to accelerate it. This needs a lot of preparation but for a 6G this seems a possible way.
2. Transportable tablespace is possible in 8.1, so you can upgrade your database to 8.1 and do the transportable tablespace export/import.
3. Finally, you can do the upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1 to 10.2 to 12.1:

   - [Choose an Upgrade Method for Oracle Database (12c)](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/preup.htm#UPGRD12359)
   - [Choose an Upgrade Method (10g)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14238/preup.htm#i694345)

I think all these methods are possible for your database (6Gb, 12h downtime), and the method you choose should be tested thoroughly.

You should not forget that besides your database your clients must be upgraded and tested, too. Here Oracle describes the major upgrade steps:

- [Major Steps in the Upgrade Process for Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/intro.htm#UPGRD52705)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but a complement to the other answers.

Where I work, we had to move data from old 9.2 Oracle database to 11.1 Oracle databases. The old database was on AIX and the new one was on RHEL or Oracle Linux.

To me, there is no "good" answer and it depends on a lot of factors :

- how big is the database ?
- how much down-time is affordable ?
- what kind of objects are used in the database ?
- What budget do you have for purchase ?
- How much time are you given to prepare the operation ?
- What options are installed ?
- etc.

We used (mainly) two different techniques to migrate databases.

The first one was classically to export with "exp" utility and import with "imp" utility with the import done in NOARCHIVELOG as it slows down the migration process. 
The downtime required for this operation depended on the size of the database. 
To minimize this downtime (we needed once to migrate a 500 G database in 1 hour...), we spent time and development efforts on making a cold-hot data segmentation, a table/partition transfer duration-based prioritization, a synchronization between source and target servers so that the import started directly once the export ended and finally added parallelism into all of this.

The second one was a home made solution which does the same thing as Golden Gate mentioned in another answer : 
  1) Replicate structures (tables, views, functions etc.) either using exp/imp tools with ROWS=N 
  2) Fully transfer the snapshot of a table and start to keep track of modification using triggers on tables, a global sequence for operations and a logging table. 
  3) Make use of this logging table for incremental loads. Once you want to actually migrate databases, make your incremental loads more often so that you reduce your downtime to the minimum.
This method was unsure until 9.2.0.8 version as there were bugs in triggers for LOB objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The noarchivelog is on the target server

Answer (score 1):

I supported 8.0.5 databases at the beginning of my career in the late 90's. I need to point out the transportable table spaces and data pump were added in 9i. You could go through 8i to get to 12c, but it would be better to do it in one shot.

Think if this problem as if you are migrating from a non-Oracle database to Oracle. You should be able to use heterogenous gateway to ODBC to connect from the new database to the old database.

[Database Gateway for ODBC User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODBCU/intro.htm#ODBCU100)

Now you can read data directly from 8.0.5 to 12c. Next get the DDL for creating all of your tables and create a script that will create the users and all of the tables. You can probably run the migration of data in parallel by creating several jobs that can run using the 12c scheduler. Each job would simply do insert into the target table without any constraints. If you have any tables that use long, long raw or raw you need to write an external program to migrate those using: c, pro*c, Perl, etc. Once you can migrate the data you need to generate the ddl for enabling the constraints. Finally if you have stored procedures or triggers in the database you should rewrite them.

This seems like an iterative process that will probably run many times over months trying to get the conversion correct and complete, and have it run in the allotted 12 hours. You can do this, but it will take some effort. The good news is that while the conversion will take time, you should not need to lose data or take an exceptionally long down time. So people can keep using the application during that time.

Comment: In the early 90s there were no 8.0 databases. It was released 1997. http://www.dadbm.com/roadmap-oracle-database-releases/

Comment: Sorry, typo. I started working with Oracle in 1997. Does that mean that nothing I said is valid?

Comment: I'm not sure that even ODBC would work.  I'm hard-pressed to think of a version of the Oracle client that could be installed on an operating system that can run 12.1 that would be able to connect to an 8.0.5 database.

Comment: They OP would just need to test several ODBC drivers. 8.0.5 would likely use a 7 bit characterset. 12c would likely be UTF8. I would try the Microsoft Generic Oracle ODBC driver. Since almost no one has Oracle 8.0.5 running it is going to be a case of trial and error.